# How can I automatically create a list of files and folders in a given folder in LibreOffice Calc?

Tags: nautilus, automation, libreoffice

How can I automatically create a list of files and folders in a given folder in LibreOffice Calc ?
I'd like it to have as much info as possible (size, name, folder hierarchy...) sorted in nice little cells.
I'd rather not dump it to a file using ls and then trying to sort it manually: it creates an awful output.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet would be to use a scripting language (Ruby, Python, Perl etc.) to create a text file in CSV format with this data. Calc can import CSV text files as spreadsheets.

An example Ruby script to get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'csv'
table = [['Name', 'Size', 'Path']] #These are your headings - you can change them
Dir['./*'].each do |file|
    table << [File.basename(file), File.size(file), File.expand_path(file)]
    #You can add extra columns with extra information in the above line
end
File.open('output.csv', 'w') do |f|
    f.puts table.map {|row| CSV.generate_line(row) }.join("\n")
end
```

Run this in the appropriate directory then open the file 'output.csv' with Calc. Use the following settings on the 
import:

[image: calc CSV import]